# vue.js - method can't iterate over array property

Tags: vuejs2

My app reads json data array from an api via axios.
I store the array in an app property. All is fine, I can check and see the array data is there.

When a method should iterate over the array, it gives an error message:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"
```

This is the code in my app:

```
"use strict";

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        diskstatus: null,
    },
    methods: {
        hasServer: function (serverName) {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.diskstatus.length; i++) {
                if (this.diskstatus[i].ServerName == serverName) {
                    return 'Y';
                }
            }
            return 'N';
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios
            .get('api/diskstatus')
            .then(response => {
                this.diskstatus = response.data.rows;
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            });
    }
});
```

Any idea why the code in the method does not see the property as an array?

I can console.log the array and it looks perfect.
Thank you in advance for your feedback!

Comment: `diskstatus` is set to `null` initially. Maybe the `hasServer` call is happening before the stati are loaded?

Comment: Show the HTML where you're trying to `v-for`.

Comment: Show return by kindness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, `v-for` cannot operate on `null` because `null` is not *iterable*.

If you're trying to use `v-for` over a property that initially is `null` and only later, asynchronously, becomes an `Array`, you have two options:

1. Initialize `diskstatus: []` instead of `null`
2. On the element where you're trying to `v-for`, add a guard: `v-if="diskstatus"`.

Comment: My fault was to initialize the property to null instead of []. It works perfect now! In addition, I like the idea to guard an output!